# Is there an inbuilt Monitoring solution for Nifi Processors where sometimes the processor getting hung can be reported

Tags: apache-nifi, cloudera, health-monitoring

Is there an inbuilt Monitoring solution for Nifi Processors where sometimes the processor getting hung can be reported.
Also like for now we are creating some dummy data and passing that through the flow and using the MonitorActivity processor seeing if it is getting stuck or not.
Is there any more efficient solution for the same?

I am looking if NiFi already has a functionality where alerts are triggered if the processor is hung for sometime.